# ./src/index.js Line 10: 'elementid' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, compiler-errors, react-router

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import *  as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import App from '/App';

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
<App/>
</BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById(elementid, 'root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

i just type in this code in index.js file on reactjs then this error will be occurred

```
Failed to compile
./src/index.js
  Line 10:  'elementid' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

so please tell me , what should do for fix this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Dom Render requires an element reference, so you have to provide reference using document.getElementById('root'). just remove elementid

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?

`getElementById` only receives 1 argument, that is the id of your element. So if you are trying to get the root element. Just change it to:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import *  as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import App from '/App';

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
<App/>
</BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: i edit it then this error occur  ./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './serviceWorker' in 'D:\education\saww\assignment02\src'